# jOOQ - General way to insert multiple data and get generated IDs

Tags: java, sql, jooq

what is the general way to insert multiple data via jooq, when I need the generated key of each element?

Normally I would use a batch insert, which is not possible at the moment because of [this](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3327).

I could use create.newRecord(...) and insert each element separately. Afterwards, the ID is set correctly, but this approach has a bad performance.

I hope someone has a better approach, I cannot be the only one who need this feature...

Thanks a lot in advance,
tohoe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found yourself, jOOQ 3.4.2 currently has the limitation documented in issue [#3327](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3327) with respect to fetching IDs after [`DSLContext.batchStore()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchInsert-org.jooq.TableRecord...-).

A workaround that might work well enough would be to create a big `INSERT .. RETURNING` statement with all your records, such as:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .insertInto(TABLE)
   .set(record1)
   .newRecord()
   .set(record2)
   .newRecord()
   ...
   .returning()
   .fetch();
```

This is just a workaround, of course, and might not even perform as well as batching, as the statement could possibly turn out to be quite large.

Comment: What about using batch mode? Is this any faster than doing `batchInsert`?

Comment: What do you mean by "batch mode"? I cannot comment on this being faster or not. You need to benchmark this on your database.